# WebAPI Routing With Known and Dynamic Parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamic, get, routes

I'm trying to build a get action in WebAPI (C#) which will respond to the following:

[http://{host}/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/{MyId}/{dynamic parameters I have no control on}](http://%7Bhost%7D/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/%7BMyId%7D%7Bdynamic%20parameters%20I%20have%20no%20control%20on%7D)

For example: [http://{host}/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/7?param1=abc&param2=def](http://%7Bhost%7D/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/7?param1=abc&param2=def)

and also: [http://{host}/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/7](http://%7Bhost%7D/api/Callback/CompleteFlow/7)

I've created an action with the following signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage CompleteFlow(int MyId, string requestParams)
{
}
```

and added specific routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Callback",
                routeTemplate: "api/Callback/CompleteFlow/{MyId}/{*requestParams}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Callback", action = "CompleteFlow", requestParams = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I'm getting MyId parameter but not the dynamic parameters into the requestParams parameter within the action (I'm expecting to get requestParams=param1=abc&param2=def, but gets null instead).

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix this using the following approach:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage CompleteFlow(int MyId)
{
    var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
}

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Callback",
                routeTemplate: "api/Callback/CompleteFlow/{MyId},
                defaults: new { controller = "Callback", action = "CompleteFlow" });
```

Hope it helps somebody :)

Thanks,
Nir.